# Send username and password to user's email Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send the username and password to the user's email when the administrator adds them to the system.
How should I set this `$message->setBody('Your Username is <b>$username</b> <br> Your Password <b>$password</b>', 'text/html'); });` to fetch the username from the textbox and the password which is autogenerated.

```
public function adduser(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $username = $request->input('username');
        $password = Hash::make(str::random(5));
        $dateadded = $request->input('dateadded');

        if ($email != '' && $username != '' && $password != '' && $dateadded != '')
        {
            $data = array('email' => $email, "username" => $username, "password" => $password, "dateadded" => $dateadded);
            $value = AdministratorModel::adduser($data);

            if ($value)
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('User Added');</script>";

                Mail::send([], [], function($message){
                    $message->from('sealtravels19@gmail.com','Seal Travels');
                    $message->to('yvonnekusiima00@gmail.com', 'Yvonne');
                    $message->subject('Login Credentials');
                    $message->setBody('Your Username is <b>$username</b> <br> Your Password <b>$password</b>', 'text/html');
                });
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Login Credentials sent');</script>";

                return redirect()->action('AdministratorController@userrecords');
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('User already exists');</script>";
                return view('Administrator/AddUserView');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i can't understand what's the question

Comment: @Berto99 I’m trying to get the username that will be typed in the username textbox to be sent to the user’s email

Comment: you can't interpolate the the php variable in the string using `'` you need to use `"` double quotes ... and you also will then run into a scoping issue as those 2 variables are outside the scope of that anonymous function

Comment: @lagbox used double quotes they worked.

Answer (score 1):

I used double quotes and called the username from the textbox using `$username = ($_POST['username']);`

```
                    Mail::send([], [], function($message){
                    $username = ($_POST['username']);
                    $message->from("sealtravels19@gmail.com","Seal Travels");
                    $message->to("yvonnekusiima00@gmail.com", "Yvonne");
                    $message->subject("Login Credentials");
                    $message->setBody("Your Username is <b>$username</b> ", "text/html");
                });
```